# How to explicitly mark `Source.combine` to use a "concat" strategy?

Tags: akka-stream

I want to conditionally prepend a (non-materialized) `Source` with a value. How should I do this?

```
val src: Source[_,NotUsed] = ???
Source.combine(Source.single(???), src)
```

The [`Source.combine`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#combine) documentation mentions

> using a given strategy such as merge or concat

, but does not provide an example on selecting concat strategy.

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
Source.combine( Source.single(None), tmp2 )(Concat[T])
```

`T` being the value of elements you want in the source.

Answering my own question since I think this can be useful for others, and there was no existing answer on SO.